# GIT Setup in Jenkins to find the correct pom.xml file

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, pom.xml, git-branch

I have a Git repository that contains several project with same root directory with the following structure,

+-repo

```
 +--Root folder

    +--- projectA
       +--- pom.xml

    +--- projectB
       +--- pom.xml
```

I want to built independent jenkins jobs. I need to know what is the location that I need to give in the branch specifier or in the maven build path.

I get an error - The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory